# How to get current geo points only once in iphone?

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I am using following code in viewDidLoad method

```
 CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation; 
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then below method is called continuously when location changed.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

But I want current geo points only once. Is there any method which gives you directly current geo points? I want to calculate distance between current geo points and other location when I click some button. please help me if any one knows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` you can call

```
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
```